# How can I make the xmlserializer only serialize plain xml?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xml-declaration

I need to get plain xml, without the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` at the beginning and `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` in first element from `XmlSerializer`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 272, accepted):

To put this all together - this works perfectly for me:

```
// To Clean XML
public string SerializeToString<T>(T value)
{
    var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

    using (var stream = new StringWriter())
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value, emptyNamespaces);
        return stream.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: using (var stream = new StringWriter()) can be changed to var stream = new StringWriter(); Gives error with code analysis as it tres to dispose xmlwriter twice.

Comment: @Archna If you did that, the StringWriter would not be disposed in the case that the XmlWriter.Create call throws an exception. A possible solution that covers malicious XmlWriter authors making an IDispose implementation that does not conform to the guarantee that executing Dispose twice does nothing for the second call would involve a try catch and setting stream to null inside the `using( writer )`, as can be seen in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11192524/2144408.

Comment: What are you using the type-parameter T for?

Comment: So the key here is `settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;`. See [XmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 28):

Use the `XmlSerializer.Serialize` method overload where you can specify custom namespaces and pass there this.

```
var emptyNs = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, objectToSerialze, emptyNs);
```

passing null or empty array won't do the trick

Comment: Please note that you need to combine this answer with @tobsen's answer to get what I was asking for - a really clean xml!

Answer (score 16):

You can use **XmlWriterSettings** and set the property **OmitXmlDeclaration** to true as [described in the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings(VS.80).aspx). Then use the **XmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, objectToSerialize)** [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335857(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

This will write the XML to a file instead of a string.  Object ticket is the object that I am serializing.

Namespaces used:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Code:

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ticket));

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true,
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true
};

using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(fullPathFileName, settings))
{
    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, ticket, emptyNamespaces); 
}
```