# Create XML with XmlDocument C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I need to create an XML with this structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:res="http://resource.webservice.correios.com.br/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <res:buscaEventos>
         <usuario>ECT</usuario>
         <senha>SRO</senha>
         <tipo>L</tipo>
         <resultado>T</resultado>
         <lingua>101</lingua>
         <objetos>JS331400752BR</objetos>
      </res:buscaEventos>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However it is wrong out this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:res="http://resource.webservice.correios.com.br/">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <res:buscaEventos xmlns:res="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <usuario>ETC</usuario>
      <senha>SRO</senha>
      <tipo>L</tipo>
      <resultado>T</resultado>
      <lingua>101</lingua>
      <objetos>JS331400752BR</objetos>
    </res:buscaEventos>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**The difference is in buscaEventos**

I created in the following way
  `XmlNode eventosNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement 
( "res " , " buscaEventos " " http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ " ) ;` How do I remove the xmlns : res only that node ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772004/how-can-i-make-the-xmlserializer-only-serialize-plain-xml

Comment: google that first before you come here and you will get the answer; there are loads of blog posts and SO posts about how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `res` namespace is mapped to `http://resource.webservice.correios.com.br/` at the root, but when you created `buscaEventos` you remapped it.

This may solve the problem:

```
 XmlNode eventosNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("res", "buscaEventos"
     "http://resource.webservice.correios.com.br/" ) ;
```

Comment: Tanks for help  man :)