# Attempting to serialize a class without a namespace or declaration

Tags: xml, vb.net

I've been following the solution found on [How can I make the xmlserializer only serialize plain xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772004/how-can-i-make-the-xmlserializer-only-serialize-plain-xml) in an attempt to only serialize plain text however I'm running into a few problems as I do this on the VB.net side

The aim is to prevent the lines `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>` and attributes `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` from showing

I have a sub as follows:

```
  Private Sub writeXMLContent()
        For Each dataItem As dataClass In dataSet            
            Dim emptyNameSpace As XmlSerializerNamespaces = New XmlSerializerNamespaces({XmlQualifiedName.Empty})
            Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(dataClass))
            Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings
            settings.Indent = True
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = True

            Using stream As New StringWriter
                Using writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings)
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, serializer, emptyNameSpace)
                    'will write each line to a file here
                End Using
            End Using
        Next
    End Sub
```

however I keep coming across the same two errors:

1. The line `Using writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings)` throws an error using operand of type object must implement system.iDisposable
2. The line `serializer.Serialize(writer, serializer, emptyNameSpace)` seems to not like my second parameter as it expects an object? I'm not too sure what object I would pass here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `XmlWriter` does not implement `IDisposable`, i.e., it has no `Dispose` method that the [Using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) could call. Simply fix it by not using the Using-statement.

   ```vb
   Dim writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings)
   ```
2. The second parameter must be the object that you want to [serialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.serialize?view=net-6.0#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlSerializer_Serialize_System_Xml_XmlWriter_System_Object_), i.e., probably `dataItem` in this case.

   ```vb
   serializer.Serialize(writer, dataItem)
   ```

As for removing the namespaces and the comment, here is a solution:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim dataItem = New DataClass With {.Id = 5, .Name = "Test"}

    ' Serialize.
    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(DataClass))
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Using writer As New StringWriter(sb)
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dataItem)
    End Using

    Dim xml = RemoveNamespaces(sb.ToString())

    Console.WriteLine(xml)
End Sub

Private Function RemoveNamespaces(ByVal xml As String) As String
    Dim doc = New XmlDocument()
    doc.LoadXml(xml)

    ' This assumes that we have only a namespace attribute on the root element.
    doc.DocumentElement.Attributes.RemoveAll()

    Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings With {.Indent = True, .OmitXmlDeclaration = True}
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Using stringWriter As New StringWriter(sb)
        Using writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings)
            doc.WriteTo(writer)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

It is using this test class

```vb
Public Class DataClass
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Once the change for the writer was done - the serializer was happy so it seemed to be linked somehow!