# How to serialize a class instance to XML in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to serialize a class instance of the following class into a XML string.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot]
public class Orders
{
   [XmlElement("Order")]
   public Order order { get; set; }
}
```

The serializations works fine, but I want to remove the two defaults attributes from the `Orders` element. Although I need another encoding (ISO-8859-1) and I have to add other attributes to the `Orders` element.

I wanted to solve the latter by adding a `[XmlAttribute]` to the `Orders` class, but it results in the same output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Orders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Order>
      ...
   <Order>
</Orders>
```

Does anybody know, how I could achieve that? I highly appreciate any kind of help, cheers! (:

---

My current root class, which should have a root attribute

```
public class AGTOSV
{
   private string _attribute = "Hello World";

   [XmlAttribute]
   public string xmlns
   {
       get { return _attribute; }

       set { _attribute = value; }
   }

   // ....
```

Comment: You cannot make a class an attribute.  Only properties can be attributes.

Comment: @jdweng I know - Thats what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you just want to export plain xml.

Then you need to set XmlWriterSettings as below and tell the serializer to use a empty namespace.

```
var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
};

using (var stream = new StringWriter())
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(orders.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(writer, orders, emptyNamespaces);
    string xml = stream.ToString();
}
```

Also see [How can I make the xmlserializer only serialize plain xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772004/how-can-i-make-the-xmlserializer-only-serialize-plain-xml).