# c# Deserializing xml to class "xmlns was not expected"

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization, xmlnode

I want to deserialize a XML node to a class, with all the subnodes values into class properties

I got this error

- ```
    ex  {"There is an error in XML document (1, 2)."}   System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}
  ```

and the message of the exception

- ```
    InnerException  {"<LITERALS xmlns=''> was not expected."} // If i use InnerXml it would be REVISION xmlns...
  ```

I tried Outer and Inner XML with a lot of solutions that appear in stackoverflow.
I dont know why it adds xmlns

My xml is like that:

```
<root>
  <LITERALS>
    <REVISION>Rev.</REVISION>
    <SERIE>Serie</SERIE>
  </LITERALS>
  <MORENODES></MORENODES>
  <MORENODES></MORENODES>
</root>
```

And my class Literals to deserialize the xml node

```
{
    // I tried these options that i saw in a post
    // [XmlRoot(ElementName="LITERALS")]
    // [Serializable, XmlRoot("LITERALS")]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "www.idk.com", ElementName = "LITERALS", DataType = "string", IsNullable = true)]
    public class Literals
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "REVISION")]
        public string REVISION { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SERIE")]
        public string SERIE { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My code

```
                XmlNode literalsNodo = courseNodo.SelectSingleNode("LITERALS");
                XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute("LITERALS");
                xRoot.ElementName = "LITERALS";
                xRoot.Namespace = "http://www.idk.com";
                xRoot.IsNullable = true; 
                  
                 
                if (literalsNodo != null)
                {

                    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Literals),xRoot);
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(literalsNodo.InnerXml));

                    literals = (Literals)xs.Deserialize(ms);
                }
```

Comment: You're missing a Root class, aka a class that can deserialize your root element that contains a property with your Literals class.

Comment: What are you adding namespace to the xml classes when you do not have any namespaces in the xml?  Remove namespace attributes in the classes.

Comment: It's missing the namespace. Should be `<LITERALS xmlns="http://www.idk.com">` so your XML does not match your class attribute

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640395/10024425, https://stackoverflow.com/a/72589790/10024425, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/68215415/10024425.