# Is it possible to send the XML request body both with and without the xmlns attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-4.7.2

My C# .NET Web API (v4.7.2) application currently has a request body called with xmlns attribute, but another new users sends request to the same endpoint without any attributes. I use `System.Xml.Serialization`. I tried many times, but I couldn't build a structure to run both at the same time. Can we do this too? If not, do you have any other suggestions?

**Sample 1:**

```
<YourModel>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
    <Age>30</Age>
    <Address>
      <City>New York</City>
      <Street>Main Street</Street>
      <ZipCode>10001</ZipCode>
    </Address>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <Age>28</Age>
    <Address>
      <City>Los Angeles</City>
      <Street>Hollywood Blvd</Street>
      <ZipCode>90001</ZipCode>
    </Address>
  </Person>
</YourModel>
```

**Sample 2:**

```
<YourModel xmlns="http://abcxyz.com">
  <Person>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
    <Age>30</Age>
    <Address>
      <City>New York</City>
      <Street>Main Street</Street>
      <ZipCode>10001</ZipCode>
    </Address>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <FirstName>Jane</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <Age>28</Age>
    <Address>
      <City>Los Angeles</City>
      <Street>Hollywood Blvd</Street>
      <ZipCode>90001</ZipCode>
    </Address>
  </Person>
</YourModel>
```

Comment: Visual Studio has a tool to assist in creating classes from XML. Add a new class to your project then copy your XML to the clipboard (highlight the XML, then press ctrl-C). Then in VS, click _Edit_ => _Paste Special_ => _Paste XML as Classes_.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72589790/10024425

Comment: No.  The namespace is hardcoded in the YourModel class as an attribute : [XmlRoot(ElementName = "YourModel", Namespace = "http://abcxyz.com")]

Comment: Maybe receive it as bare XML, strip the namespace then deserialize it. TBH you should be wary of allowing such a permissive API. The spec is the spec, don't allow users to dictate what should or should not be allowed like that.

Comment: Is it possible that the lacking namespace ` xmlns="http://abcxyz.com"` is defined at a higher level than the body?

Comment: Names spaces are overused, poorly understood, and in most cased provide little value (mostly just overhead), so feel free to get rid of them in almost every situation.  The only time you need them is when you have some developer that blindly follows "standards".   Your spec should require no-namespace to really mess with those guys : ). To your question see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/205709/c-xml-without-declaration-and-namespace